# Set min-height in pixes tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I don't think this question has been answered.

min-h-1/2 and the rest variants are working correctly, but how to set lets say `min-height-30px`?

I did not see the answer in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a custom scale property in the `minHeight` section of your `tailwind.config.js` file.

tailwind.config.js

```
  minHeight: {
   '30px': '30px',
  }
```

sample html:

```
<div class="min-h-30px bg-blue-600">min-h-30px</div>
```

check working [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/fYZBePY57X?file=config)

Comment: i did that. Did not work. Tried both under extend property and out of it

Comment: Ok, the height i was using was too small to notice. Turns out it works. Thanks